# django-cms default menu extend Menu or CMSAttachMenu?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am trying to build a very simple, wiki-type site using django-cms.

I have 1 app, with 2 models defined:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    label=models.CharField

class Topic(models.Model):
    ...
    cat = models.ForeignKey('topics.Category',
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    help_text=u'Please choose a category for this topic',
    null=True
)
```

I am trying to have the default menu show the Subject classes as the top-level options, with the Topic classes as sub-levels for each Subject. There will be 4 Subjects altogether. E.g.:

Subject 1

-topic1

-topic2

Subject 2

-topic3

-topic4

etc..

I have read all the django-cms docs, and I'm still confused. In my menu.py, should I be extending Menu or CMSAttachMenu? Do I need 4 different generators? How do I reference the ForeignKey field when using the generator?

I am a beginner, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```py
# menu.py

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from cms.menu_bases import CMSAttachMenu
from menus.base import NavigationNode
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool

from .models import Subject


class SubjectsMenu(CMSAttachMenu):
    name = _("Subjects Menu")

    def get_nodes(self, request):
        nodes = []
        cnt = 0
        for subject in Subjects.objects.all():
            subject_node_id = cnt
            node = NavigationNode(
                subject.label,
                reverse('subject_view_detail', args=(subject.pk,)),
                subject_node_id
            )
            nodes.append(node)
            for topic in subject.topics.all():
                cnt += 1
                node = NavigationNode(
                    topic.name,
                    reverse('topic_view_detail', args=(topic.pk,)),
                    cnt,
                    subject_node_id  # parent
                )
                nodes.append(node)
            cnt += 1
        return nodes

menu_pool.register_menu(SubjectsMenu)
```

Then you can add this menu to your AppHook or attach it from the admin.